# python check if value starts with

Tags: python

Can't we check if a value starts with a string?

I have a dict that contains :

```
my_dict = {'category': 'failure', 'logged_product': 'log_prd1', 'product': 'prd1', 'backlog_month_done': None,'TDC': <__main__.TDC object at 0x010F47D0>}

for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if value.startswith('<__main') :
    #removeit
```

why does it work with key and not with value? how can I do it ?
any help would be appreciated

I am getting the error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: What are the contents of `my_dict` ?

Comment: `value` needs to be a string or some other object that has a `startswith` method. Please check the types of your values.

Comment: Probably, if this is exactly what you're running, because `'<__main'` has been typed, and `value` is not in the same scope of your `if` clause.

Comment: Assuming whoever changed the whitespace hasn't changed the problem

Comment: @user1734229 what actual error do you get? Something like "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswtih'"?

Comment: i have edited my question, actually I was wrong, the value is not a string. Any idea on how I can delete that value? Knowing that the key is unknown (I have put just an example in my question)

Comment: You shouldn't use `.startswith()` to filter values of random types (str, None, object).

Answer (score 7):

The [`startswith` method is available for string objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), so it looks like `attr` is a string, but `value` is not.

From your edit, it looks like one of your values is `None`. To fix, you should change this in your `my_dict`:

```
'backlog_month_done': None
```

to this:

```
'backlog_month_done': ''
```

You can also check if `value` is a string type:

```
for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
        continue
    if value.startswith('<__main') :
    #removeit
```

Comment: is there a way to do this dynamically please? I should loop over `my_dict` and test if `value == None` ?

Comment: If you want to skip `None` values (or non-string types in general), then yes, you can check.  I'll edit in an example.

Answer (score 1):

> if value.startswith('<__main') :

This code is likely designed to find `<__main__.TDC object at 0x010F47D0>` but it doesn't work because your `dict` contains a `None` value and the `<__main__.TDC object at 0x010F47D0>` that you see is merely a textual `repr`esentation of an object, but it's not a string.

If you are sure that you truly want such a heterogeneous `dict`, then you should instead filter based on what you get from `isinstance` (or `type`).

```
for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if not isinstance(value, basestring) :
        continue # if you really want to remove it, use del my_dict[attr] here instead
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because `my_dict['backlog_month_done']` is `None`.

You can fix this using an extra condition in your if:

```
my_dict = {'category': 'failure', 'logged_product': 'log_prd1', 'product': 'prd1', 'backlog_month_done': None,'TDC': <__main__.TDC object at 0x010F47D0>}

for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if value and value.startswith('<__main'):
        #removeit
```

However, I doubt this will do what you expect, as the value for `TDC` in `my_dict` is not a string: it's an instance of a class that you've copy and pasted the `repr` of, so you will likely get a message like

```
AttributeError: 'TDC' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

You can check prevent that by checking `value` is a `str`:

```
for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if isinstance(value, str) and value.startswith('<__main'):
        #removeit
```

However,m I suspect that that isn't what you want at all.  If you want to check if a value is an instance of TDC, you need to pass `TDC` as an argument to `isinstance`:

```
for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if isinstance(value, TDC):
        #removeit
```

Alternatively, if you're sure you want to remove anything that (even the repr of) starts with "<__main", you need to make sure you get a string of the item.  In this case, you probably want to use the `repr` function, as `str` is frequently overloaded to return a custom value.

```
for attr, value in my_dict.items() :
    if repr(value).startswith('<__main'):
        #removeit
```

Comment: the problem is that `TDC` is just an example, and my dict contains a lot of values starting with `<__main`, so I want to do it dynamically....

Comment: @user1734229 In that case, you need to turn them into strings.  Will edit above.

Comment: @user1734229 Edited, but you really want to consider if this is the right way to do what you're trying to. Using `repr` in real code is generally considered a "code smell".  Look at what other rules define the values you want to remove.